# How to focus next input when limit reaches but if input is nested within Html li tag in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

I have my 6 inputs beside each other in one row like this

component.html

<li *ngFor="let i of [1,2,3,4,5,6]">
<input class="form-control" placeholder="0" type="text" maxlength="1" (keyup)="onDigitInput($event)">

Now i tried this in my `controller` to `focus` next `input` element when `maximum` length limit reaches automatically.

```
onDigitInput(event: any) {
  let element;
  if (event.code !== 'Backspace')

  element = event.srcElement.nextElementSibling;
  console.log('Element : ',event.srcElement)

  if (event.code === 'Backspace')
    element = event.srcElement.previousElementSibling;

  if (element == null)
    return;
  else
    element.focus();
}
```

But the problem with my solution is that it will only work if all `input` elements must be beside each other without wrapping/nesting in further element. But in my case my each `input` element is wrapped in `<li>` tag so that's why it's not working. So can any one suggest any solution to for this problem via any function or even `directive` if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I adapted the solution you posted to accomodate the structure that you have (`input`s inside `li`s).

```
  onDigitInput(event: any) {
    const element = this.getNextInput(
      event.srcElement,
      event.code === "Backspace"
    );

    if (!element) {
      return;
    }

    element.focus();
  }

  getNextInput(currentInput: Element, isBackspace: boolean): HTMLElement {
    if (!currentInput) {
      return null;
    }
    const parentListItem = currentInput.parentElement;
    let nextListItem = isBackspace
      ? parentListItem.previousElementSibling
      : parentListItem.nextElementSibling;
    return nextListItem?.firstChild as HTMLElement;
  }
```

Comment: But in your answer where you are checking the condition that input value reached to it's maximum length or not?